# Filter rows after grouping the data pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the data below

```
   a   b
1  12  1
2  14  2
3  12  3
4  12  3
5  14  1
6  12  4
```

I have to group the data according to the column (a)..after which i have to delete the rows which has the same (b) value. Below i have shown what it should look like,

```
   a   b
1  12  1
2  12  4
3  14  1
4  14  2
```

is there any easy way in pandas to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the duplicates with `keep` parameter specified as `False`:

```
import pandas as pd
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

#    a  b
#1  12  1
#2  14  2
#5  14  1
#6  12  4
```

If there are more columns in the data frame, columns can be explicitly specified as `df.drop_duplicates(['a', 'b'], keep=False)`

Comment: nope..i have to group the data according to column a...then from each grouped set i have to delete the duplicates

Comment: @AnnaSsaa How is that different from dropping rows that thave the same a and b values?

Comment: oh yea..why did I not think of that..thanks!